# How to validate non-clashing time ranges on items submitted through PowerApps?

Tags: date-time, validation, powerapp

I have a SharePoint list with a start time and an end time, which will be entered through a PowerApps app.

One of the core rules is that those time ranges should not clash, similar to a meeting room booking.

With a native SharePoint form I would simply use PreSaveItem() and Moment.js to check if the time range clashes with any other time range.

How do I do something similar with PowerApps?